# How to solve python error: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python, class, init

I am new to Python. Can someone please help me to solve this error?

My code is as following,

```
class First:
    def passThisArgs(self, a, b, c):
        return Second(self, a, b, c)

class Second:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        print 'Values are :\n', a, b, c

newObj = First()
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7
newObj.passThisArgs(a, b, c)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/abc.py", line 13, in <module>
    newObj.passThisArgs(a, b, c)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/abc.py", line 3, in passThisArgs
    return Second(self, a, b, c)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I am using python 2.7 in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass "self" to another class.  Python will create a brand new object and pass that automatically as the `self` parameter to `__init__`. So:

```
        return Second(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Okay. thanks @tim-roberts, this solved my error. I just figure out that `self` in `return Second()` will create a new object and passed it into __init__ of `First()`.

Comment: Thanks again. I learned a new concept. When I captured the `self` from `passThisArgs`, I got it as following `<__main__.First instance at 0x2>`. Means every `self` in a class will create its own object and we can also use the variables and method from that `self` also in another class(if passed it, as i first passed it mistakenly).